# How to set the short-cut icon generated by installation of an .msi using a VS2017 Deployment Project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been tasked to change the Icons associated with a WPF VS2017 application that I did not create. I am trying to change the desktop short-cut icon that is automatically loaded on installation of the app's .msi.

This solution uses a Visual Studio Installer Project to generate the deployment .msi.

I have tried to change the file reference in the deployment project, but it seems to hang on to the original icon.

I have even gone to the extent of renaming the new .ico file with the original .ico filename and putting it into the directory where the original was located, but the .msi continues to load the old icon to the desktop on the application's installation.

- Is there user documentation (not tutorials) on the Visual Studio Installer add-on?
- More directly, how is the desktop short-cut icon specified in the deployment project?

Extensive web searching and experimentation have not presented an answer.

Comment: _Is there user documentation (not tutorials) on the Visual Studio Installer add-on?_ I don't think so, but there is a [Q&A page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects#qna).

Comment: Is the icon you want to use embedded as a resource in the application (exe file) that is installed? If so, you can select the icon from that file.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I am trying to use an icon that is embedded as a resource (it is used as the icon for the app), but I haven't be able to figure out how to tie it into the build in the Deployment Project so that it is used to create a shortcut for the application on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer project has a "file system" view. 
Click round on your files under setup and it should appear in your code editing area.

Under File system on target machine will be folders.

These might have been configured to explicitly add a specific icon for the shortcut.

Click users desktop in the left panel.

You will have a shortcut in the right.

Select this and take a look at properties.

There's an Icon property which is probably set. Click the icon, browse and choose the one you want. This should be in the list of setup files.

If not, check your main entry point project has an icon set.

Choose it's properties > Application

In there under Icon and Manifest set the ico file.

Then try again.